# Pegar os dados de uma coluna em uma view e inserir em uma tabela

Tags: tabela-html, view

boa noite, estou com um problema, quero pegar os dados de uma coluna em uma View que criei e colocar esses dados em uma coluna de uma tabela, segue a baixo o código que usei para criar a View, já estou a duas semanas tentando resolver isso mas não tem jeito.

create view bolsa
as
select
nome as nome,
case
when LEFT(nome,1) = '*' then
'bolsa'
when RIGHT(nome,2) = '**' then
'inclusao'

end as class

from tbl_user

estou usando o mysql workbench 6.3

Answer (score 0):

Vou exemplificar com base somente nas informações que você colocou na pergunta. Vamos lá:

Para fazer o que você deseja, se não tiver faltando nenhuma informação, é teoricamente simples. Segue um exemplo de como fazer:

```
INSERT INTO nome_da_tabela (nome_da_coluna)
SELECT nome_do_campo_da_view FROM nome_da_view;
```

Observe que na primeira linha está um insert para a coluna da referida tabela. Na segunda linha, também de forma simples, está um select buscando o nome da coluna da View a qual você quer inserir na tabela.

Caso você queira, pode colocar alguma condição no Select com o objetivo de filtrar o resultado e inserir somente o que lhe interessa na tabela.

Como disse anteriormente, seria interessante você colocar mais informações, como por exemplo, a SQL das tabelas e views envolvidas na questão.

Se ainda ficar alguma dúvida é só dizer que respondo logo em seguida.

Grande abraço.